# Display the weight of cart and order items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, cart

How can I to put the weight of each item under your description on the cart page and the payment page in woocommerce?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 6):

***2020 Updated***

The following code will display the subtotal item weight for cart and order items everywhere:

```
// Display the cart item weight in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Weight subtotal', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  ( $cart_item['quantity'] * $cart_item['data']->get_weight() )  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save and Display the order item weight (everywhere)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_order_item_data', 20, 4 );
function display_order_item_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( $values['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Weight subtotal', 'woocommerce' ), ( $values['quantity'] * $values['data']->get_weight() )  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit') );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you want to display the product weight instead, in cart and order items you will use:

```
// Display the cart item weight in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( $cart_item['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  $cart_item['data']->get_weight()  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit')
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save and Display the order item weight (everywhere)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_order_item_data', 20, 4 );
function display_order_item_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( $values['data']->get_weight() > 0 ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ), $values['data']->get_weight()  . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit') );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you !!

Would it be possible to put the unit of kilos ???

Weight: Value "KG"

 works perfectly

Thank you

Comment: @LoicTheAztec 
It looks like there is a small error in your answer. 
At the `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` hook you use  `$cart_item['data']->get_weight()` 
while the parameter is `$item`

Comment: @7uc1f3r Oups! thank you very much, I have updated the code… On `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` hook, the correct argument to be used was `$values` instead of `$cart_item`…

Answer (score 0):

**go to directory** 
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\cart
and add code there

```
 <tr>
         <th>Total Weight</th>
        <td><?php echo WC()->cart->cart_contents_weight . ' ' . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit'); ?></td>
        </tr>
```